# Keep old URL after redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How do I keep the URL after redirecting to a new server?

I have a server on Amazon, with a IP address for its URL. I also have a domain name which I got from nic.ru (a Russian hosting company). I paid $5 and got nic.ru to do a redirect to my new server.

When the redirect goes through, the URL that is displayed is the Amazon server IP (that is, I type http://bezpontavto.ru which is redirected to http://54.186.37.214/; but 54.186.37.214 is then displayed in the URL bar) I want the URL to redirect from http://bezpontavto.ru to http://54.186.37.214/ yet still display as http://bezpontavto.ru in the URL bar.

I dont have access to the apache.conf file at nic.ru (they do it automatically). I have however set up mod_rewrite, on my new server, and have a nice new blank .htaccess file set up in the /var/www/html/ directory.

What do I need to do to display the old URL in the url bar?

(I guess this is pretty simple, but I have been hitting my head against the wall all day, any help would be much appreciated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get nic.ru to set up A records that point to your new server. This is usually possible without additional charges, and there is usually a DNS configuration interface to make it possible.

Your Amazon server needs to have been prepared to serve the .ru domain (Apache needs to have a `VirtualHost` entry set up).

Comment: Thanks Pekka... I took a new look at the nic.ru control panel, there was a option for Address masking (I think it will do a frame redirect). So I selected that, should see in 4hrs if it worked. You really helped me out, thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Setting up DNS would be much preferable to a frame redirect, though - with a frame redirect you can't have deep links for the domain, and the IP will show up in search engines rather than the domain name

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking fo do a frame redirect from nic.ru, you have to do it under the menu item "My Domains" (Мои Домены):
[image]

To do a DNS redirect, which Pekka mentioned was superior, nic.ru offers a DNS service. The details are at http://dns-master.ru/tariff/en/